# Decomposition of complete graph into cycles through all vertices.

Tags: graph-theory

**Decomposition of complete graph into cycles through all vertices.**

for $n$=5,7,9

Answer given-:

"View the vertex set of$K_{n}$ as $Z_{n}$ , the values 0, . . . , n−1 in cyclic order. Since each vertex has degree $n-1$ and each cycle uses two edges at each vertex, the decomposition has $\frac{n-1}{2}$  cycles."

Not getting this point.please somebody explain !

Furthur please help me to find the answer !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a simpler way is
$$\frac{\text{number of edges}}{\text{number of edges per cycle}} = \frac{n(n-1)/2}{n}=\frac{n-1}{2}.$$

But if you want to understand their argument, think of it this way. Suppose the decomposition into cycles exists. Take one of the cycles and erase it. Each vertex loses two of its outgoing edges. Continue removing cycles, and at each step each vertex will lose two of its outgoing edges. Since the degree of each vertex is $n-1$, the graph will be empty after $\frac{n-1}{2}$ steps.

Comment: can you please ellaborate for $n$=4 !number of cycle=$\frac{3}{2}$..!

Comment: @sourav The sentence that you quoted is *under the assumption that such a decomposition exists.* The fact that $\frac{n-1}{2}$ is not an integer when $n$ is even proves that such a decomposition cannot exist when $n$ is even.

Comment: Why a graph having number of vertces $n$=$9$ not possible? though using the formula $\frac {n-1}{2}$ give 4!!