# Decomposition of complete graph $K_{n}$ into cycles through all vertices.

Tags: graph-theory

Decomposition of complete graph into cycles through all vertices.
Continuing explanation [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1985647/decomposition-of-complete-graph-into-cycles-through-all-vertices/1985652#1985652),
Next explanation is given as

for $n=5$ , $n=7$, it suffices to use cycles formed by traversing the
vertices with constant difference:$\left(0,1,2,3,4\right)$,$\left(0,2,4,1,3\right)$ for $n=5 $

and

$\left(0,1,2,3,4,5,6\right)$,$\left(0,3,6,2,5,1,4\right)$ for $n=7 $

Not getting how 
$\left(0,1,2,3,4\right)$,$\left(0,2,4,1,3\right)$  and  $\left(0,1,2,3,4,5,6\right)$,$\left(0,3,6,2,5,1,4\right)$ is coming from !!!!!

Please help me out!!

Answer (score 1):

As the description sketches, we sum a constant number to the value of the vertices. It should be assumed that the sum reads modulo $n$, so $4+2 = 6 = 1 $.

Now note that the sequence $0 - 1 - 2 - 3 - 4 - 5 - 6 $ has constant iterated difference 1, whereas  $0 - 3 - 6 - 2 - 5 - 1 - 4 $ has constant iterated difference 3.

Comment: I accept $ 0 - 1 - 2 - 3 - 4  -5  - 6 $ belongs to a cycle but not getting how  $ 0 - 3 - 6 - 2 - 5  -1  - 4 $

Comment: You know that this is a cycle because all edges are distinct (and it's clear that they belong to the graph, since it's the complete one) and all vertices occur. The real question that you should ask is whether the edges on both cycles are disjoint. To show this fact suppose you have an edge $i - j$ that occurs in both cycles. This means (with a little bit misleading notation!! Careful) that $|i-j| = 1$  and $|i-j| = 3$ at the same time, which is impossible for any two numbers modulo 7.

Note however, that it would be possible for $|i-j| = 3$ and $|i-j| = 4$, for $i=5$ and $j = 2 = 9$.